# Parse Data from JSON URL

Tags: php, json, parsing

I'm trying to get data onto my website by parsing data from a JSON format. The URL is http://api.bfhstats.com/api/onlinePlayers and I'm trying to output for example the currently players online on PC.

Here's the current code I have:

```
<?$json = file_get_contents("http://api.bfhstats.com/api/onlinePlayers");
$data = json_decode($jsondata, true);
echo $data->pc->peak24;?>
```

I thought this would work, however it's not displaying anything. I am very new to parsing JSON data so if someone could explain what I'm doing wrong that would be brilliant.

Comment: See one error in your code: $json and $jsondata

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change:

```
$data = json_decode($jsondata, true);
```

to

```
$data = json_decode($json, true);
```

Also, json_decode returns an array so use:

```
echo $data['pc']['peak24'];
```

to access the data.

Comment: Just to clarify, `json_decode` returns an associative array when the second parameter is set to true. If he changes it to false (or leaves it as default) he can use his existing code.

Comment: Changed it now, however nothing is displaying. I think it's the format of which i've called the json objects. Thanks for the fast response

Answer (score 1):

You first call the variable `$json` but then use `$jsondata` in json_decode.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `foreach` cycle to fetch the two dimensional array `$data`:

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents("http://api.bfhstats.com/api/onlinePlayers");
$data=array();
$data = json_decode($json, true);
//print_r ($data);
foreach ($data as $pc) { 
    echo $pc["peak24"]."<br>";
}
?>
```

Check the `$json` and `$jsondata` that have different name but should be the same.